# AngularJS - How to store mouse coordinates on mousemove?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Trying to translate something I had working without angular to work *with* angular, and it seems I understand angular less clearly than I thought:

I have a number of static divs and one movable div that follows the mouse. If the user clicks while the movable div is overlapping a static div, it triggers an event (currently a Bootstrap modal). Currently, it also calculates the distance of the mouse and the static divs and changes the background color based on distance (i.e. closer to the red div, background is brighter red, closer to blue div, background brighter blue, between the two, the colors fade/blend from red to purple to blue, etc).

Currently, I am just trying to capture mouse position when the mouse moves.
The next object is to find the centerpoint of each static div.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [ng-mousemove](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMousemove) directive and pass the mouse event to your angular controller.

See this [plnkr](https://plunker.co/edit/3OzIp1Pehy) for an example.

**View**

```
<div class="big" ng-controller="TestCtrl" ng-mousemove="captureCoordinate($event)">
    <div>x: {{x}}</div>
    <div>y: {{y}}</div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
   $scope.captureCoordinate = function($event){
      $scope.x = $event.x;
      $scope.y = $event.y;
   }
```

In tandem with the ng-mousemove directive, you can pass the $event object to your controller function and grab x and y coordinates off of there.

Comment: Thanks much, that is exactly the sort fo thing I was looking for! Based on this, I was looking entirely in the wrong direction.

Comment: No problem! There are a bunch of "ng-" prefixed attributes that you can hook up, all of which give you the $event object for free. Please mark the answer as accepted so if others have the same question, they know there is an answer. Thanks!

Comment: ...Having tried to adapt your setup to what I have, it has a strange result - it says the x and y are undefined on localhost but it works the same as yours when put into a plnkr. https://plnkr.co/edit/KWmigwnlejXDojeqmXFX

Comment: Interesting, is anything on the $event defined or is that undefined as well?

Comment: well... console.log("X: " + $event.x + " Y: " + $event.y+ ", X: " + $scope.x + " Y: " + $scope.y); returns "X: undefined Y: undefined, X: undefined Y: undefined"

Comment: Are you able to use the developer tools and put a breakpoint in your $scope.currentPos function to see what the $event object looks like. Does it have any properties on it?

Comment: solved it! plunker leaves $event.x as a valid and defined output, but localhost needed it to be offsetX or pageX to make it function. thanks again for the help.

Comment: nice! I was going to suggest that, that's why I wanted to see if there was anything on the $event object. Glad to help and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
angular.directive('mouseMoveDirective', mouseMoveDirective);
function mouseMoveDirective() {
  return {
    link: link
  }

  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    $(element).mousemove(function(e) {
      var pageCoords = (e.pageX + ":" + e.pageY);
    })
  }
}
```

Benefit of using directive is that its reusable.